# Can't find simplification error when finding all values of $\log(\sqrt{i})$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I'm currently in a complex analysis course and on one of our problem sets we were asked to find **all values** of $\log{\sqrt i}$. The complex logarithm, $\log$, was defined in class as: $\log(z) = \textrm{Log} |z| +i*\textrm{Arg}(z) + 2\pi in$, where $\textrm{Log}$ is the real logarithm and $n \in \mathbb Z$.

I got that the final answer was $-\textrm{Log}(2)+i\left(\frac {\pi}{4} + 4 \pi n\right)$.

The TA for the class took off points for simplification errors and told me to look at the solution guide (there is no solution guide). I tried plugging into Wolfram Alpha but Wolfram only gives the single value for the principle branch, but we need the general solution.

After looking back over my work I can't seem to find where I made an error so I was hoping someone could catch my mistake. I attached a picture of my work below. Any clarification would be much appreciated so I don't make the same mistake on my midterm!
Thanks!

[my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRkAv.png)

Comment: You seem to be implying that $\log |\sqrt{i}| = 2$; why is that? Why do you have $4\pi n$ at the end, and not $2\pi n$?

Comment: $z^2=i$ has 2 solutions. Which one is $\sqrt i$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet - Presumably both, as it says to find __all values__. But maybe it meant all values of the logarithm, with just one value of the square root.

Answer (score 1):

I see several errors.

1. In the middle of the page you didn't distribute the $1/2$: $$\qquad e^{1/2(i\pi/2+2\pi ni)}\\\overset?=e^{i\pi/4+2\pi ni}$$
2. In the blue part you miscalculated the absolute value: $$\sqrt{\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)^2}\overset?=\frac12$$
3. Below the blue part you combined $i2\pi n+i2\pi n=i4\pi n$. The problem is that these were two arbitrary integers, not necessarily the same. It should be something like $i2\pi n_1+i2\pi n_2=i2\pi(n_1+n_2)=i2\pi n_3$, where $n_3\in\mathbb Z$ may or may not be even. (But this is still incorrect because it's based on the 1st error.)